# My function wont compile properly

Tags: c++, string

I'm getting the following error when trying to compile the following function:

```
Error: invalid operands of types int and const char [3] to binary operator
```

How do I fix this?

```
string getFormattedDate()
{
    formattedDate = Date.getDay() << "/" << Date.getMonth() << "/" << Date.getYear();
    return formattedDate;
}
```

Comment: Are you *sure* that you're compiling with a Java compiler? "const char [3]" doesn't sound like it to me. Likewise Java uses `String` rather than `string`, and all the `Date` methods are *instance* methods. Then there's the matter of trying to use `<<` for concatenation, of course.

Comment: Ah, it was leppie who added the Java tag, somewhat unfortunately.

Comment: How is `formattedDate` declared ?

Comment: am I right that you try to use `<<` operator to concat strings?

Comment: You should use stringstream I think, and use `<<` instead of `=`.

Comment: this is not where the code won't compile. show all your code please

Answer (score 8):

You can't do that, it's not valid C++. Maybe you want:

```
#include <sstream>

// ...

string getFormattedDate()
{
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << Date.getDay() << "/" << Date.getMonth() << "/" << Date.getYear();
    formattedDate = ss.str();
    return formattedDate;
}
```